# Where can I find SIM settings in Huawei Ideos X5?

Tags: settings

I want to unlock my SIM card password. I was looking around Android settings, but I couldn't find SIM settings to unlock password.

Comment: What phone do you have? Manufacturers customize the settings, so the answer is different for different phones.

Comment: I'm having Huawei Ideos X5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have an Samsung Galaxy S4 using a custom ROM*. Maybe something like `Settings > Security > Set up SIM/RUIM card lock`, but it's different for every phone.

For your Huawei Ideos X5, `Settings > Location & security > Set up SIM card lock`.

Comment: Yes I'm using Huawei Ideos as you said it was there in Security settings. Thank you for your instant answer

Comment: @AristoMichael Can you provide the correct path to the settings? I will update my answer, and maybe you can accept it.

Comment: Settings > Location & security > Set up SIM card lock

Comment: @AristoMichael Thanks! Have updated the answer. :)